# How to properly use TIOCGICOUNT

Tags: embedded, linux-device-driver, tty

I'm writing a small piece of code to detect framing/parity/overrun issue on serial port on a Linux kernel 4.1.21.
From what I understand, TIOCGICOUNT ioctl should allow me to get the `serial_icounter_struct` containing the counter for framing/parity/overrun errors:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1.21/source/include/uapi/linux/serial.h#L100

The way I see it, I can pull the `icount` variable when I need to and compare it to the previous one. But that means keeping track of a variable for each serial port.

Is there any better way to manage this?

Comment: What do you think the relationship between `TIOCGICOUNT` and "errors" is? They appear be be unrelated.  What does "manage errors" even mean?  What errors?  You should be more specific about what you are trying to do, as it stands it is far too vague.

Comment: The edit is useful - I was looking at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html, which specifies only modem control line event counters.  I'd withdraw my "unclear" close vote and replace it with a "too broad" or "opinion based" close vote if I could, but would still vote to close.

Comment: Everything you need is tracked via kernel. Check */proc/tty/driver/serial*. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125183/how-to-find-which-serial-port-is-in-use